# Why when converting Float to CGFloat Xcode give me a warning "Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer"?

Tags: iphone, swift, swift2, xcode7, uicolor

I am trying to convert a Float value to CGFloat Value, here my code:

```
    let myFloatForR = 0
    let r = CGFloat(myFloatForR) 
    let myFloatForG = 0
    let g = CGFloat(myFloatForG)
    let myFloatForB = 0
    let b = CGFloat(myFloatForB)
    let myFloatForA = 0
    let a = CGFloat(myFloatForA)
    tintColor.getRed(r, green:&g, blue:&b, alpha:&a)
```

but suddenly the Xcode gives me a warning says: "Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer" on the "tintColor" line?
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the `CGFloat` objects as `var` instead of `let` and pass pointer object for red value in `getRed` method.

**Updated Code**

```
let myFloatForR = 0
var r = CGFloat(myFloatForR)
let myFloatForG = 0
var g = CGFloat(myFloatForG)
let myFloatForB = 0
var b = CGFloat(myFloatForB)
let myFloatForA = 0
var a = CGFloat(myFloatForA)
tintColor.getRed(&r, green:&g, blue:&b, alpha:&a)
```

**OR**

You can optimize your code after declaring `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` using single line of code.

```
var r: CGFloat = 0, g: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
tintColor.getRed(&r, green:&g, blue:&b, alpha:&a)
```

Answer (score 0):

They need to be optional:

```
let myFloatForR: Float = 0
var r: CGFloat? = CGFloat(myFloatForR) 
let myFloatForG: Float = 0
var g: CGFloat? = CGFloat(myFloatForG)
let myFloatForB: Float = 0
var b: CGFloat? = CGFloat(myFloatForB)
let myFloatForA: Float = 0
var a: CGFloat? = CGFloat(myFloatForA)
tintColor.getRed(r, green:&g, blue:&b, alpha:&a)
```

Edit: As deoKaushal pointed out, they also cannot be constants.

Comment: it gives me a new warning "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat?' with an argument list of type '(Int)" @Swinny89

Comment: That's because they were Ints, I have amended my answer